# O uso de PushAsync<TViewModel> no MVVM permite a chamada de várias páginas. Como evitar isso?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

Tenho um **Button** que aciona um **Command** cuja **Action** é um **PushAsync< TViewModel >()**.
O problema é que se clicar no botão mais de uma vez antes de abrir a nova tela, ele vai abrir mais de uma tela. E isso acontece em todo o MVVM quando usado o PushAsync.
Jà tentei fazer uso do IsBusy da BaseViewModel, sem sucesso. Não sei mais o que fazer e estou pensando seriamente em abandonar o MVVM por causa disso. Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

```
 public async void ActionAdicionar() {    
            if (IsBusy) return;
            else IsBusy = true;

            await PushAsync<AdicionarItemViewModel>();

            IsBusy = false;
        }
```

Comment: já tentou colocar um await na chamada do actionAdicionar no event handler do botão?

Answer (score 0):

Use um contador, que se houver mais de 1 voce não executará a função do PushAsync.
E ao voltar/iniciar a tela original, zere o contador.

```
public async void ActionAdicionar() {  
    int contador = 0;
    if (contador == 0) 
    {
       await PushAsync<AdicionarItemViewModel>();
       contador++;
    }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

O evento é executado rapidamente e usar contadores para este caso não é o suficiente. Com uso de CanExecute o sistema fará o bloqu

Command:

```
Command command = new Command(x => { ActionAdicionar(); }, (x) => { return podeExecutar; });
```

Seu método:

```
public async void ActionAdicionar()
{
    podeExecutar = false;
    
    await PushAsync<AdicionarItemViewModel>();
    
    podeExecutar = true;
}
```

Variável auxiliar:

```
bool podeExecutar = true;
```